# How can I put the value of a symbol's width/height into a text field on an artboard?

Tags: sketch-3, sketchapp

I'd like to take the width/height of an element or symbol in Sketch and have that value displayed in a Text element on an artboard. As you scale the element or symbol, the Text element is updated on the artboard with the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native option to do this kind of thing with Sketch App (v50.2).

Try making [your own plugin](https://sketchapp.com/extensions/plugins/) for this.